# How can we replace strings according to requirements?

Tags: string-manipulation

In a text, we need to replace `whitenode` with `yellownode` only when the character 'a' appears within the last pair of {} in each line.

```
whitenode {b} at (-2, 7) {a};
whitenode {a} at (-3, 7) {c};
whitenode {c} at (-4, 7) {c};
```

I know how to identify whether a line contains "{a}"

```
text = Import["G:\\a.txt", "Text"];
    replaceRule[str_String] := 
      If[StringContainsQ[str, "{a}"], 
       StringReplace[str, "whitenode" -> "yellownode"], str];
newText = replaceRule /@ StringSplit[text, "\n"];
Export["G:\\new_a.txt", newText, "Text"]
```

but I don't know how to determine if "a" is inside the last bracket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try something along these lines

```
StringReplace[
  text, 
  RegularExpression["(?m)^whitenode(.*{a};$)"] -> "yellownode$1"]
```

This solution relies on some assumptions. It doesn't account for extra whitespace at the beginning or end or inside the braces and it assumes that you're looking for exactly "{a}", not something that contains "a" like "{abc}". So, if this is overconstrained, we can adjust based on the actual structure of your data.

**Update thanks to @Roman**

```
StringReplace[
  text, 
  RegularExpression["(?m)^whitenode(?=.*{a};$)"] -> "yellownode"]
```

This is cleaner. The `?=` indicates a lookahead, which adds a requirement to the match without including the lookahead characters in the resulting match itself. So, we don't need to carry around the group and reference it in the replacement rule like I did above.

**Notes on regular expression**

Let's break down this regular expression.

```
(?m)^whitenode(.*{a};$)
```

The `(?m)` specifies multi-line mode. It's not actually part of the matching pattern, but just a sort of flag that indicates we want `^` and `$` to match the start and end of each line rather than just the start and end of the whole string.

The `^` indicates the start of a line (since we're in multi-line mode).

`whitenode` is an exact character sequence pattern.

The next bit gets interesting. `(.*{a};$)` is surrounded by parentheses so that we can refer to it later. Parentheses can be used to group things, but during the matching process, if such a group is matched, it is remembered and can be referred to in the replacement rule. The reference is done by the order of groups. So,  in the replacement, `$1` refers to the first group. That's why the right hand side of our rule is `yellownode$1`. We just take everything after the `whitenode` and plop it after a `yellownode`.

Within our group, we have `.*{a};$`. The `.*` just matches any character sequence. The `{a};$` matches exactly the sequence `{a};` as long as it appears directly before the end of a line (indicated by `$`).

Comment: You could also use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=...)` to avoid using `$1` in the right-hand side of the replacement and only strictly replace `whitenode` by `yellownode` if it is followed by the right thing: `StringReplace[text, RegularExpression["(?m)^whitenode(?=.*{[^{}]*a[^{}]*};$)"] -> "yellownode"]`

Comment: @Roman Nice!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Using `StringReplace`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```

I am using the following file:

```
text = Import["C:/b.txt", "Text"];
```

> ```
> "whitenode {b} at (-2, 7) {a};
> whitenode {a} at (-3, 7) {b};
> whitenode {c} at (-4, 7) {c};
> whitenode {b} at (-2, 7) {a};
> whitenode {a} at (-5, 7) {d};
> whitenode {c} at (-4, 7) {c};"
> ```

```
newtext = 
 StringReplace[text, 
  "whitenode" ~~ x : Except["\n"] .. ~~ "{a};" :> 
   "yellownode" <> x <> "{a};" ]
```

> ```
> "yellownode {b} at (-2, 7) {a};
> whitenode {a} at (-3, 7) {b};
> whitenode {c} at (-4, 7) {c};
> yellownode {b} at (-2, 7) {a};
> whitenode {a} at (-5, 7) {d};
> whitenode {c} at (-4, 7) {c};"
> ```

```
Export["C:/new_b.txt", newtext, "Text"]
```